# ¿Cómo hacer para que el nodo de un arbol binario almacene en un solo nodo, 4 variables?

Tags: c++, árboles-binarios

Ya había formulado anteriormente una pregunta similar pero más generalizada, me di cuenta que lo que hacía la pregunta era declarar lo que necesitaba más no especificar mi pregunta. [¿Cómo hacer un árbol en c++ que represente un campeonato deportivo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59751/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-%C3%A1rbol-en-c-que-represente-un-campeonato-deportivo). Mi pregunta específica es, como hacer para que el nodo de un arbol binario almacene en un solo nodo 4 variables, el primero, la variable string del jugador local, el segundo, la variable string del jugador visitante, el tercero la variable entero del jugador local que tiene almacenado sus puntos o goles, y el cuarto la variable entero del jugador visitante que tiene almacenado sus puntos o goles.

Basicamente como esta en este grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que para crear un nodo de un arbol hay que hacer lo siguiente:

```
ABB crearNodo(int x)
{
     nodo* nuevoNodo = new nodo;
     nuevoNodo->nro = x;
     nuevoNodo->izq = NULL;
     nuevoNodo->der = NULL;

     return nuevoNodo;
}
```

y para insertarlos:

```
void insertar(ABB &arbol, int x)
{
     if(arbol==NULL)
     {
           arbol = crearNodo(x);
     }
     else if(x < arbol->nro)
          insertar(arbol->izq, x);
     else if(x > arbol->nro)
          insertar(arbol->der, x);
}
```

Teniendo previamente una estructura similar a:

```
struct Nodo
{
  int datos;

  Nodo* izq;
  Nodo* der;
};
```

Mi pregunta es, como hacer para que en vez de que el nodo solo tenga una variable x, tenga más variables relacionadas a x, es decir, tenga 4 que variables que correspondan a un solo nodo, y que cuando las vaya a imprimir, me salgan las variables como en el gráfico. La verdad es que esto me parece bastante complejo de entender y agradecería mucho sus respuestas

Comment: No entiendo que crees una nueva pregunta cuando esto ya te lo respondí en la otra pregunta... si no vas a prestar atención a las respuestas,  ¿podemos ignorar tus preguntas?

Comment: @eferion, reportar como duplicado/pedir moderación/ignorar.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no me parece tan serio como para reportarlo. Realmente las preguntas que se hacen son diferentes... el problema es que ya le respondí a esas dudas en la otra pregunta porque me adelanté a sus problemas. Es más una falta de respeto que un tema de moderación de preguntas.

Comment: @eferion, me refiero a que puedes optar por cualquiera de estas opciones.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave lo se, pero como te digo es más un tema personal de respeto hacia la gente que responde más que un tema que requiera moderación.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo tienes hecho.

En tu código, haces

```
struct Nodo {
  int datos;
  Nodo *izq;
  Nodo *der;
};
```

Nada te impide usar una estructura para almacenar los datos; por ejemplo:

```
struct Datos {
  string local;
  strict visitante;
  int localg;
  int visitanteg;
};
```

No se si se te permite crear operadores personalizados; si te es posible, puedes añadir los operadores que precises (`<`, `==`, `!=`, ... ). Si no, pues le añades los métodos que necesites.

Ahora, cambiamos algo el `Nodo`:

```
struct Nodo {
  Datos datos;

  Nodo* izq;
  Nodo* der;
};
```

Y cambiamos el resto de funciones:

```
ABB crearNodo( struct Datos &d ) {
  nodo* nuevoNodo = new nodo;

  nuevoNodo->datos.local = d.local;
  nuevoNodo->datos.visitiante = d.visitante;
  nuevoNodo->localg = d.localg;
  nuevoNodo->visitanteg = d.visitanteg;

  nuevoNodo->izq = NULL;
  nuevoNodo->der = NULL;

  return nuevoNodo;
}
```

Y cambios similares con el resto del código:

```
void insertar(ABB &arbol, Datos &d ) {
  if(arbol==NULL)
    arbol = crearNodo( x );
  else if( x < arbol->nro )
    insertar(arbol->izq, x );
  else if( x > arbol->nro)
    insertar( arbol->der, x );
}
```

Idealmente, habría que hacer una plantilla, pero eso lo dejamos para otra pregunta ;-)